# Why is this dynamic programming code incorrect?

Tags: java, dynamic-programming

I am doing [this](http://www.codechef.com/problems/E1) problem for a homework assignment. I have solved the problem using a standard bottom up Dynamic Programming algorithm. My code shows the expected outcomes on my test cases but the website says that it gives incorrect answer. I cannot understand where this code is lacking. Please help me.

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
class Main300{

public static void main (String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception{
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
    int nn = Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());
    for(int j = 0 ; j < nn; j++){
        int n = Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());
        char[][] a = new char[n][n];
        int ki = -1;
        int kj = -1;
        for(int i = 0 ; i < n ; i++){
            String s = br.readLine();
            for(int k = 0 ; k < n; k++){
                a[i][k] = s.charAt(k);
                if(a[i][k] == 'K'){
                    ki = i;
                    kj = k;
                }
            }
        }
        System.out.println(ans(a, ki, kj));
    }
}

private static int ans(char[][] a, int ki, int kj){
    int[][] x = new int[a.length][a.length];
    for(int j = a.length-1; j >= 0; j--){
        for(int i = 0 ; i < a.length; i++){
            if(a[i][j] == 'P'){
                x[i][j]++;
            }
            if(i-2 >= 0 && j+1 <= a.length-1 && a[i-2][j+1] == 'P'){
                x[i][j] += x[i-2][j+1];
            }else if(i-1 >= 0 && j+2 <= a.length-1 && a[i-1][j+2] == 'P'){
                x[i][j] += x[i-1][j+2];
            }else if(i+2 <= a.length-1 && j+1 <= a.length-1 && a[i+2][j+1] == 'P'){
                x[i][j] += x[i+2][j+1];
            }else if(i+1 <= a.length-1 && j+2 <= a.length-1 && a[i+1][j+2] == 'P'){
                x[i][j] += x[i+1][j+2];
            }
        }
    }
    return x[ki][kj];
}
}
```

Comment: Try to include the question itself to the site as the other site may remove that link and then this question is just of no use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following are the reasons for wrong answer:

a) As the DP formulation will be

`a[r][c] = max(a[r-2][c+1], a[r-1][c+2], a[r+1][c+2], a[r+2][c+1])`

so you need to verify each and every path from the current position. What your code suggest is that you go and do it only on one path(the `else if's` simulate travelling through one path only).

b)Also as @Vinayak pointed out, `a[i-2][j+1] == 'P' will allow you to move to only those places where there is a pawn, which is not necessarily true. You can think of very trivial examples to verify this.

Here is the code:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

class e1_test{

    public static void main (String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception{
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        int nn = Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());
        for(int j = 0 ; j < nn; j++){
            int n = Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());char[][] a = new char[n][n];
            int ki = -1;
            int kj = -1;
            for(int i = 0 ; i < n ; i++){
                String s = br.readLine();
                for(int k = 0 ; k < n; k++){
                    a[i][k] = s.charAt(k);
                    if(a[i][k] == 'K'){
                        ki = i;
                        kj = k;
                    }
                }
            }
            System.out.println(ans(a, ki, kj));
        }
    }

    private static int ans(char[][] a, int ki, int kj) {
        int[][] x = new int[a.length][a.length];
        for(int j = a.length-1; j >= 0; j--) {
            for(int i = 0 ; i < a.length; i++) {
                if(a[i][j] == 'P') {
                    x[i][j]++;
                }
                int temp=0;
                //note the changes from else if's to only if's
                //removal of [i-2][j+1] == 'P' condition. 
                if(i-2 >= 0 && j+1 <= a.length-1) {
                    if(temp < x[i-2][j+1])
                        temp = x[i-2][j+1];
                }
                if(i-1 >= 0 && j+2 <= a.length-1) {
                    if(temp < x[i-1][j+2])
                        temp = x[i-1][j+2];
                }
                if(i+2 <= a.length-1 && j+1 <= a.length-1) {
                    if(temp < x[i+2][j+1])
                        temp = x[i+2][j+1];
                }
                if(i+1 <= a.length-1 && j+2 <= a.length-1) {
                    if(temp < x[i+1][j+2])
                        temp = x[i+1][j+2];
                }
                x[i][j] += temp;
            }
        }
        return x[ki][kj];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I will slightly modify your approach. You will find that this is very useful for DP solutions. This will help you write a simpler solution, and you will solve your WA on your own :)

Instead of checking for bounds, make the table `TAB` (`x` in your code) a little bigger, depending on your relation.

Value of `TAB[r][c]` is equal to max number of pawns it can capture starting from `(r, c)`

In *The White Knight* problem, see how Knight can go 2 rows above and below, and 2 columns to the right. So make your `TAB[N+4][N+2]` instead of `TAB[N][N]`. Fill this extra space with base value, `0` in this case.

[image]

The relation is pretty simple (which you have coded using 4 `if-else`)

```
TAB[r][c] = max(TAB[r-2][c+1], TAB[r-1][c+2], TAB[r+1][c+2], TAB[r+2][c+1])
```

And of course increment `TAB[r][c]` if `INP[r][c] == 'P'` (`a` in your case)

Lastly the final solution is `TAB[ki+2][kj]` (`ki, kj` from your code).

Comment: thanks for the input detailing how to make the table a little bigger but it did not solve my problem anyway. You have still used the same DP as I am. Please help me point out any mistakes in my code.

Comment: @NikunjBanka: See the EDIT in answer.

Comment: @VinayakGarg the `if-else` part is wrong as all the four branches of max will not be traversed.

Comment: @AmanDeepGautam: You are right, had OP followed my answer, he would have got accepted, removing my EDIT.